# CSS Text-Shadow color

Tags: css, inheritance

Is it possible to make the text-shadow property inherit color? like maybe:

```
text-shadow: 1px 2px inherit;
```

I know this won't work but if there is another way, please show me.

Comment: Which color would you like to inherit?

Comment: the color of the text of its parent

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try [`currentcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword):

> The `currentColor` keyword represents the calculated value of the
>   element's [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) property. It allows to make the color properties
>   inherited by properties or child's element properties that do not
>   inherit it by default.

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 1px 2px currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: red">Red</p>
<p style="color: green">Green</p>
<p style="color: blue">Blue</p>
```

Comment: Nice, what is the cross browser compatibility like?

Comment: @JSouthward See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Browser_compatibility): Chrome 1.0, Firefox 1.5, IE 9, Opera 9.5, Safari 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Well if I were you I would do that with css. I'd define some clases for text color and depending on it, change the color of shadow. Like this:

```
.text-red p{
  text-shadow: 1px 1px red;
}
.text-green p {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px green;
}
.text-blue p {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px blue;
}
```

And then in my HTML

```
<div class="text-blue">
<p>
     My shadowed text
</p>
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pzvuw07g/1/ 
I don't know other way. I hope it will help!

Answer (score 2):

You actually have only to set the shadows properties, text-shadow color, like `box-shadow`, `outline` or `border` inherits the color used by text, wich is indeed  `currentcolor`, default value :)

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 1px 2px ;
  outline: solid;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  border:solid;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: red">Red</p>
<p style="color: green">Green</p>
<p style="color: blue">Blue</p>
```